# Share Workbook getting checked on exporting excel from asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop, export-to-excel

How to uncheck "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time." in Share Workbook in excel while exporting the excel from c#

I am using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" for exporting the excel

Comment: Show the code you're currently using (or at least stripped down version)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this works. You will have to test it.

Create a new class that inherits from Excel.Worksheet.

```
class myExcelWorkSheet : Excel.Worksheet
{
    public bool MultiUserEditing { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create an instace of myExcelWorkSheet instead of the standard one. In the example above we added the set; to MultiUserEditing. This will allow us to change that property.

```
myExcelWorkSheet myWorkSheet = new myExcelWorkSheet();
myWorkSheet.MultiUserEditing = false;
xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(myWorkSheet);
```

While this does allow you to change the property I am not certain if the property is actually used when the file is saved. This you will have to check for yourself.